# Toggle is not responding in small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I created a Navbar and added searchbar and login signup options however before adding them, code for toggle was working fine and it was responding on small screens but now it is not working.
can you help me to find out where I am making mistake....

I am using Bootstrap-5 here.

I am expecting toggler to respond on small screens which is not working right now.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark shadow-10-strong bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Travel <b> Friend </b> </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <!-- Collection of Nav Links , forms and other content for toggeling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start" id="navbarNav">
      <!-- There are two ways to add feature lists one was to use UL and LI and second was to just add A tag which was easy -->
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Blog</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
      </div>

      <!-- for searchbar -->

      <form class="navbar-form form-inline">
        <div class="input-group search-box">
          <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control bg-transparent" placeholder="Search here..." />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                  <a href="#" class="material-icons nav-item nav-link">&#xE8B6;</a>
                </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- Form close here -->

      <!-- Login and Sign Up icons here -->
      <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto action-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why don't you go to the docs and copy the nav code and customize it your way

Comment: I tried but still no good. I am still not able to find out the issue. Maybe I am not that good at this.  :(

Comment: could you share your code in jsfiddle or codepen....this code doesn't work with bootstrap 5

Comment: the issue could be in the CDN...make sure you've added `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">` in head and `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` at bottom

Comment: Adding boostrap css and js, it works for me